# What is the difference and relationship between "xx-softmmu" and "xx-linux-user"?

Tags: qemu

When build `qemu` from source code, I find for every `CPU` architecture, there are 2 options for target list: `xx-softmmu` and `xx-linux-user`. For example:

```
x86_64-softmmu
x86_64-linux-user
```

I can't search the difference between two options. Could anyone introduce what is the difference and relationship between them?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To put it simply, xxx-softmmu will compile **qemu-system-xxx**, which is an emulated machine for xxx architecture (System Emulation). When it resets, the starting point will be the reset vector of that architecture. While xxx-linux-user, compiles **qemu-xxx**, which allows you to run user application in xxx architecture (User-mode Emulation). Which will seek the user applications' main function, and start execution from there.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMU#Operating_modes

Comment: To be precise, it would start from the *entry point* of the executable (usually `_start`) when using User-mode Emulation, but that's only a detail.